# Migrations ends up inside virtual environment?

Tags: django

I installed [`djang-carrot`](https://pypi.org/project/django-carrot/) package, added it to installed apps and ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, but the migrations ended up inside the virtual environment... Why is that?

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations carrot
Migrations for 'carrot':
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/carrot/migrations/0001_initial.py
- Create model MessageLog
- Create model ScheduledTask
```

The problem is, as the virtual environment is not checked in to source control, I cannot check in the migration, which normally how things are done in Django. What's the thought here? What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside `settings.py` you can change the path of `migrations directory` for each app, Try the following:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'carrot': 'to_module.folder_migrations'}
```

Comment: For future reference, how does one figure these things out?

Comment: more info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#migration-modules)

Comment: In my case, auth migartions are written in venv directory. Adding MIGRATION_MODULES = {'auth': 'users.migrations'} in my settings I have django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: auth.0001_initial error on migrate. Without the change in settings, everything works fine.